# DoDirectPayment IPN Verification

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-nvp

Is there a way to verify the IPN we get from Paypal for DoDirectPayment, credit card payments?

The notification validation mentioned on the page https://www.paypal.com/en/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside seems does not work with DoDirectPayments and returns "INVALID" with correct data too.

Is there something similar available for Paypal Payments Pro? I tried searching the web but could not find something helpful.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you also include "cmd=_notify-validate" together with the IPN message you received when performing IPN validation? The flow for IPN validation should be the same of every PayPal products. Reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/

Comment: @vandershraaf - Thanks, I was including that variable but was wrongly sending the request to Live account while I was working on Sandbox. Thanks for the help. Its sending 'VERIFIED' for correct set of data. My bad.